# How to (de)serialize immutable object with custom name for list name?

Tags: java, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize object with Jackson into XML, however I'm heaving troubles to do so...

**My object:**

- Is an immutable class with getters and constructor only
- It contains a list of sub-objects messages
- I want to serialize this list wrapped in element `<messages>` and each message as a `<message>` element - as I understood I have to place `@JsonProperty("message") @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "messages")` annotations on getters, since when I place it on a constructor, it does not produce desired output (both are the same `<message(s)>`)

```xml
    <response id="response-id">
        <messages>
            <message code="a"/>
            <message code="b"/>
        </messages>
    </response>
```

- I need to deserialize this structure, however as it's immutable object with final variables, I have to deserialize it through constructor.

**Code snippet:**

```java
    public class Playground {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
            Response response = new Response("response-id", List.of(new Message("a"), new Message("b")));
    
            XmlMapper xmlObjectMapper = new XmlMapper(new XmlFactory());
            xmlObjectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.ORDER_MAP_ENTRIES_BY_KEYS, true);
            final String value = xmlObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(response);
            System.out.println(value);
            assert ("<response id=\"response-id\"><messages><message code=\"a\"/><message "
                + "code=\"b\"/></messages></response>")
                .equals(value) : "Desired format does not match!";
            final Response deserializedValue = xmlObjectMapper.readValue(value, Response.class);
            //final String deserialized = xmlObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(deserializedValue);
            //assert value.equals(deserialized) : "Does not match";
        }
    }
    
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
    @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "response")
    @JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "messages"})
    class Response {
    
        private final String id;
        private final List<Message> messages;
    
        @JsonCreator
        public Response(
            @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id", isAttribute = true) final String id,
            @JsonProperty("message") final List<Message> messages) {
            this.id = id;
            this.messages = messages;
        }
    
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id", isAttribute = true)
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        @JsonProperty("message")
        @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "messages")
        public List<Message> getMessages() {
            return messages;
        }
    }
    
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)
    class Message {
    
        private final String code;
    
        public Message(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "code", isAttribute = true) final String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }
    
        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "code", isAttribute = true)
        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }
    }
```

- When I try to deserialize it without `messages` annotated in the constructor I get exception: `Invalid type definition for type 'Response': Argument #1 of constructor [constructor for 'Response' (2 args), annotations: {interface JsonCreator=@JsonCreator(mode=DEFAULT)} has no property name (and is not Injectable): can not use as property-based Creator`
- When I add `@JsonProperty("message")` annotation, I get exception: `Invalid definition for property 'messages' (of type 'Response'): Could not find creator property with name 'messages' (known Creator properties: [id, message])`
- When I change it to `@JsonProperty("messages")` (plural), I get: `Duplicate property 'messages' for [simple type, class Response]`
- When I add both, `@JsonProperty("message") @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "messages")`, it produces exception: `Invalid definition for property 'messages' (of type 'Response'): Could not find creator property with name 'messages' (known Creator properties: [id, message])`. (Nor any combination of message/messages in those two annotations works)

What am I doing wrong? What annotations do I need to use to retrieve desired XML output with it's deserialization?

Comment: [This article over at Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-immutable-objects) might help.

Comment: Thank you @Turing85, however my problem is not in (de)serialization of immutable objects, rather in serialization and deserialization of a list of messages in XML format with custom list and list-item name. When I customize them, I'm not able to deserialize the content. Either it's lack of my knowledge, or it's Jackson bug. Without customisation I'm able to do it, however I don't like generated structure naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future googlers:

This seems to be related to jackson-dataformat-xml issue:
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/187

There is also explanation and a workaround posted.